# MySQL Workbench charset

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1, workbench

Does there exist any way to change the MySQL Workbench charset? My schema uses UTF-8 and when I view the table data (saved as UTF-8) or add data manually, it appears with charset errors, probably MySQL Workbench uses LATIN1.

Answer (score 30):

I think OP was asking about charset that Workbench uses in its editor and how to setup Workbench to use UTF-8 in GUI - not how to setup default charset used for database table in Workbench. At the moment in Workbench one can set database table charset but regardless of it Workbench will in it's GUI represent data using Latin1 charset!!! Also inserting data into UTF-8 tables through Workbench will result with wrong chars in database. I don't know either how to make Workbench deal with UTF-8 in its GUI.

Comment: Do you recommend another sql GUI tool? whatever I enter is being displayed as ??????

Comment: My RAD is NetBeans and it has built in database browser and editor.

Comment: I also think OP was asking about the charset that Workbench uses...  most of this this this answer is wrong..   Workbench definitely handles UTF8 and utf8mb4 just find..   but the default connection charset is utf8 and you must call "SET names utf8mb4" after connecting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685368/mysql-workbench-connection-encoding

Comment: @BradKent thanks, this was what I needed as I was trying to cut/paste into a column in workbench.

Answer (score 19):

In "Model Overview", under "Physical Schemata", right-click the database and select "Edit Schema...". Define the character set to the "Collation"-field. (MySQL Workbench 5.2.35)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this worked for me; actually, charset and collation are two different things - afaiu - so I did not thought this would be the way.

Comment: In WorkBench 5.2.44, its now under Alter Schema and still called Collation. It is true that you can't enter UTF-8 characters in edits from Workbench. Such a pain.

Comment: @Mike_Laird which other GUI for SQL would you advice for MAC?

Comment: @Odelya, The MySQL Workbench is available for MAC OS X. I don't use Apple products and can't comment on any others. I would advise using Workbench for MAC. You'll get better support and can search for problem solutions from the whole Workbench community. FWIW.

Comment: note that this *does not* magically change what Workbench shows you, so if you are using a utf8mb4 column, you're still going to see nonsense bytes instead of proper unicode.

Comment: thank you very much. you saved me from editing the altering script every time I change the schema from the workbench EER diagram. and for the guys how asking for the character set not the collation. changing the collation is changing the character set implicitly

Answer (score 4):

For further reading, another fix would be to change the display font.  Go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance`.  Change the Editor font.  It could be that the default font does not display utf-8 correctly, but others do.

Oh, and if you are having trouble changing your font you can try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553386/changing-font-in-mysqlworkbench)

Comment: I've tried but I still get weird characters on the result set grid

Answer (score 1):

You have to set every fields utf8 or Table default at the alter table.

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing grid font as below.

Edit > Preferences > Fonts > Results Grid > Arial