# how to write Chinese characters into MySQL with hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, encoding

I'm making a web application with JavaScript. I'm using java servlet which is connected with MySQL database with hibernate. in Servlet there is a String in Chinese, and when I try to write that string into MySQL field it shows up as "?" in MySQL. my whole project in netbeans is set to charset=UTF-8. I tried to set collation and charset in database to utf-8, utf8mb4, big5 and none of them works. I also tried to change my column from varchar to nvarchar but when I click apply (MySQL workbench) the column is still "varchar".

this is my servlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        String tabla=request.getParameter("tabla");
        //String tabla contains chinese caracters
        String user=request.getParameter("user");
        Configuration myConf = new Configuration();
        myConf.configure("hib/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        StandardServiceRegistry service = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                applySettings(myConf.getProperties()).build();
        SessionFactory myFactory = myConf.buildSessionFactory(service);
        Session conn = myFactory.openSession();
        Transaction t = conn.beginTransaction();
       
        List<User>upislista;
        upislista=conn.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE useUsername='"+user+"'").list();
        upislista.get(0).setUseKineski(tabla);
        
        
        


        t.commit();
        conn.close();
```

Comment: netbeans and browser can recognize chinese characters, only mysql show them as "???".

Comment: Have you tried changing the font to a more utf8 friendly font? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553386/changing-font-in-mysqlworkbench        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font

Comment: I would try `GNU_Unifont` in the `Resultset Grid:`.

Comment: i tried that now and it still doesnt work. when i try to change column from varchar to nvarchar and in same tame set column collation "utf-8 default" it shows error.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 2
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `kineski`.`kineski` 
CHANGE COLUMN `kin_tekst` `kin_tekst` NVARCHAR(4000) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL

Comment: Did you restart mysql workbench after the change?

Comment: yes. i dont think that is the problem.

Comment: I don't think you should have changed "utf***". I think the characters are there. You just need a font that can display the characters properly.

Comment: i have tried to set GNU_Unifont now, and it still doesnt work..

Comment: do you have any more ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't.

Comment: Show us the connection parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate XML:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

Connection url:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_nameuseUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

The above changes were enough for me to upgrade from utf8 to utf8mb4 charset scheme.

As a side note I would like to make one clarification that UTF-8 is the character encoding while utf8mb4 is a character set that MySQL supports. MySQL's utf8mb4 is a superset to MySQL's utf8.

Spring/Hibernate filter:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Spring/Hibernate:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/miniprojetjee?useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8&characterEncoding=utf-8"/> (or maybe it is =yes)
```

"Spring":

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getRegion2", produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Answer (score 0):

不知道你用的哪个版本的mysql, 但是你需要配置mysql

```
character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

一些版本hibernate能够正确配置，但是一些版本需要你手动配置。

Comment: where do i type "character_set_server=utf8mb4". Im sorry if it is a stupid question but im beginner when it comes to mysql and hibernate.
can you please write in English because i cant read Chinese.

Comment: sorry I thought you can read Chinese. Rick James 's answer works. And if you want to get more info, you can read the official document: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html and attention the version is the right one

Comment: I will for sure, tanks.