# Square characters displayed in MySQL script

Tags: mysql

I've just installed SQL Workbench and tried to write a script, but the output appears all squarish, even though the UI itself is in English. Are there any ways to show the script in English? E.g. "SELECT * FROM table;"

Image: [SQL script appears as squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8ylF.jpg)

Configuration

- Ubuntu with encoding "Unicode - UTF-8"

Comment: Maybe try setting a different font for the editor in the configurations of SQL Workbench? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16702041/3340665

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution, tested it and worked. Thanks to Ulrich and his provided link: [stackoverflow.com/a/16702041/3340665](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16702041/3340665)

Steps

1. In the Workbench, go to Toolbar > Edit > Preferences
2. In Preferences, go to Fonts > SQL Editor > Set value as "Source Sans Pro 10"
3. Restart Workbench