# Where can I change the default character set of a table in MySQL Workbench's data modeling tool?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I created a database schema using MySQL Workbench's data modeling tool. When it generates the SQL CREATE statements, it generates "default character set = latin1;" for some tables, e.g.:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `moocdb`.`resource_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `moocdb`.`resource_types` (
  `resource_type_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `resource_type_name` VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`resource_type_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
default character set = latin1;
```

How can I change it to the schema's default character set? (I found where to change the schema's default character set, but not the table's)

---

As a [side note](https://stackoverflow.com/q/766809/395857):

> Note: Since MySQL 5.5.3 you should use [`utf8mb4`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)
>   rather than `utf8`.  They both refer to the UTF-8 encoding, but the
>   older `utf8` had a MySQL-specific limitation preventing use of
>   characters numbered above 0xFFFD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860086/mysql-workbench-charset)

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 those are different questions: the question you linked to is trying to change some MySQL workbench configuration whereas in my question I want to change the database itself.

Comment: Thanks. The duplicate came from the answer posted today (from the late answer review queue...). Your comment will be useful to anyone who sees it.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can set the used charset/collation combination in the table editor. You have to expand the header (which is by default collapsed to save space) to be able to change it. See this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is it safe to change the collation on a live production database?  What exactly does it do?

Comment: Please don't use answers to post new questions. Instead create a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot for this topic : it saves me a lot of time (I searched the  header that was just collapsed by default).

I just want to say that you can specify for the table collation the option : schema default (the first option in the collation drop list).

And then, you can specify too the collation for the text type fields : table default.

With that, you can control the collation of your database with just the global schema collation parameter.

(my mysql workbench version : 6.1.7  revision 11891 build 1788)

Enjoy

Comment: Where can I change that global schema collation parameter?

Answer (score 3):

Expand the database. Select the table from the tree view-> Right click and select alter table. You will get the following window shown in the screen shot. Here you can change the charset.[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change the entire database in the work bench...

In "Model Overview", under "Physical Schemata", right-click the database and select "Edit Schema...". Define the character set to the "Collation"-field. (MySQL Workbench 5.2.35)

Answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8149026/5579664

Answer (score 1):

When you open your model, double click (or right click and edit) on MySQL schema, and MySQL Workbench show you, settings for Charset/Collation like as figure

[image: First Case]

[image: Second Case]